# Comparing and Printing values from two dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two Python lists containing dictionaries

List1

```
[{'domain': 'www.google.com', 'visits': 100, 'sessions': 50}, 
{'domain': 'www.youtube.com', 'visits': 50, 'sessions': 20}]
```

List2

```
[{'domain': 'www.google.com', 'visits': 120, 'sessions': 55}, 
{'domain': 'www.facebook.com', 'visits': 30, 'sessions': 10}]
```

I wanted the following output

```
Domain            Visits1  Sessions1   Visits2  Sessions2 
www.google.com    100      50          120      55
www.youtube.com   50       20            
www.facebook.com                       30       10
```

I am trying to play around with itertools  and zip to figure out if I can do it on my own but I am stuck, Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show **what** you did so far. Show your code.

Comment: Well, my code is not working but here is a gist what I am trying to do  for d1, d2 in zip(expected_results, actual_results):
 for key in d1.keys():
 if d1['domain'] in d2.values():

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the data into a dict first:

```
L1 = [{'domain': 'www.google.com', 'visits': 100, 'sessions': 50}, 
      {'domain': 'www.youtube.com', 'visits': 50, 'sessions': 20}]
L2 = [{'domain': 'www.google.com', 'visits': 120, 'sessions': 55}, 
      {'domain': 'www.facebook.com', 'visits': 30, 'sessions': 10}]

res = {}

for counter, item in enumerate([L1, L2], 1):
    for entry in item:
        domain = entry['domain']
        domain_dict = res.setdefault(domain, {})
        domain_dict['Visits{}'.format(counter)] = entry['visits']
        domain_dict['Sessions{}'.format(counter)] = entry['sessions']
```

The result looks like this:

```
>>> res
{'www.facebook.com': {'Sessions2': 10, 'Visits2': 30},
 'www.google.com': {'Sessions1': 50,
  'Sessions2': 55,
  'Visits1': 100,
  'Visits2': 120},
 'www.youtube.com': {'Sessions1': 20, 'Visits1': 50}}
```

Now you print them:

```
longest = max(len(x) for x in res.keys())
header = ['Domain', 'Visits1', 'Sessions1', 'Visits2', 'Sessions2']
print('{:{w}s} '.format(header[0], w=longest), end='')
print(' '.join(header[1:]))
for domain, data in res.items():
    print('{:{w}s}'.format(domain, w=longest), end=' ')
    for head in header[1:]:
        value = data.get(head, 0)
        print('{:{w}d}'.format(value, w=len(head)), end=' ')
    print()
```

Output:

```
Domain           Visits1 Sessions1 Visits2 Sessions2
www.youtube.com       50        20       0         0 
www.facebook.com       0         0      30        10 
www.google.com       100        50     120        55
```

Don't like the zeros for missing values. Use spaces:

...

```
    for head in header[1:]:
        value = str(data.get(head, ''))
        print('{:>{w}s}'.format(value, w=len(head)), end=' ')
    print()
```

prints:

```
Domain           Visits1 Sessions1 Visits2 Sessions2
www.youtube.com       50        20                   
www.facebook.com                        30        10 
www.google.com       100        50     120        55
```

Comment: I think OP'd use `''` instead of `0`.

Comment: Yes. I think `0` is nicer. Keep as an exercise in string formatting for the OP.

Comment: Ah, because maybe `0 != None` here. ;) However, nice answer.

Comment: Thanks @Mike, I am trying to understand your code. The code which I had written was not handling values which were not common in both the lists. Looking at your code, I would have never figured out the answer because it was beyond my circle of competence.

Comment: @Sumedh Glad that it helped. The core is working with dicts. The formating of the printing is just a bit lengthy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mike, I like the logic, if you come to Melbourne, beer is on me :)

Comment: I'll take your word for it. ;)